# Check for logged in users from outside wp page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need to check if the user has logged in to my wordpress site from a non wp page.How can this be done ?

I tried to create a plugin that check for user details and returns logged in details.But when I access the plugin from outside wp.Its always returning 'not loggedin'

This is the code

```
require('../../wp-blog-header.php');
if (is_user_logged_in()){
    echo "Welcome, registered user!";
}
else {
    echo "Welcome, visitor!";
};
```

This always returns "Welcome, visitor!".
Which is the best way for checking this ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use ajax:

Add this in function.php:

```
function my_ajax_is_user_logged_in() {
  // Handle request then generate response using WP_Ajax_Response

  if (is_user_logged_in()){
    echo "Welcome, registered user!";
  }
  else {
    echo "Welcome, visitor!";
  };

  exit;
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_is_user_logged_in', 'my_ajax_is_user_logged_in' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_is_user_logged_in', 'my_ajax_is_user_logged_in' );
```

Within jquery you can access like this:

```
$.get('http://yoursite.com/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',function(data,status){
  alert(data);
});
```